# WARNING: Could not resolve Info.plist

Tags: macos, qt, qmake, info.plist

I have a strange QMAKE warning:

```
WARNING: Could not resolve Info.plist: '../../../Qt/5.4/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang/Info.plist.app'. Check if QMAKE_INFO_PLIST points to a valid file.
```

I noticed this warning sometimes depending where I create my project in the filesystem:

- ~/dev : the warning is triggered
- ~/dev/test : the warning is not trigger

The consequence is that the *Info.plist* file is not created that make the bundle invalid.

Here is my configuration:

- MacOS 10.9.5
- Qt 5.4.1
- Qt Creator 3.4.0

Comment: Do you have a custom `QMAKE_INFO_PLIST` entry in you `.pro` file? Usually you don't need that. If you have, please add the line to the question.

Comment: No I don't have this line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

qmake creates the path to the default template `Info.plist.app` relative to the source directory of the project. Expected behavior would be to have it relative to the build directory. So I'd call it a Qt bug.

In order to get rid of the error, you should have your build directory as a sibling of your source directory.

Comment: Could you add the absolute path to your Qt installation and to your `.pro` file? From there we can do the math

Comment: QMAKE_INFO_PLIST = /Users/martin/Qt/5.4/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang/Info.plist.app

Comment: My .pro file is here: /Users/martin/dev/PouetTest02/PouetTest02.pro

Comment: and my build dir is: /Users/martin/dev/builds/PouetTest02-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_clang_64bit-Debug/Makefile

Comment: In this case your build dir is not a sibling of your source dir. Did you try to compile into `/Users/martin/dev/build-PouetTest02-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_clang_64bit-Debug`?
To be honest, I did not try using absolute paths in `QMAKE_INFO_PLIST`. Better remove the line.

Comment: I manage to change my build dir level so it's the same than the pro file and it worked! This is not perfect but at least it's working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I will report this bug ASAP

Comment: Fine. I deleted the absolute path part from my answer because I am not 100 % sure whether it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

In mean time while this problem to be solved I am using post link actions to set these properties correctly:

> BUNDLE_PATH = "$${DESTDIR}/$${TARGET}.app"
>   QMAKE_POST_LINK = mkdir -p $${BUNDLE_PATH}/Contents/Resources && \
>      cp -f $${PWD}/mac/app.icns $${BUNDLE_PATH}/Contents/Resources/app.icns && \
>      cp -f $${PWD}/mac/file.icns $${BUNDLE_PATH}/Contents/Resources/file.icns && \
>      cp -f $${PWD}/mac/Info.plist $${BUNDLE_PATH}/Contents/Info.plist && \
>      cp -rf $${PWD}/mac/qt_menu.nib $${BUNDLE_PATH}/Contents/Resources/qt_menu.nib